# Action method IEnumerable<int> as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

Given this method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateInvoiceRequisition(IEnumerable<int> relevantIDs)
```

Can I somehow mark up a collection in a form field?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateInvoiceRequisition", "Invoices"))
{   
    <input type="hidden" value="1,2,3,4,5" name="relevantIDs" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

I've tried commas, semi-colons and pipes.

Do I need to resort to passing a string and parsing it myself?

Comment: Does it work as a JSON array?:  `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: IIRC, you should be able to say: `relevantIDs[0], relevantIDs[1], ...` as the HTML input name. You can't pass in multiple values at once though, you need 1 per.

Ideally you make a model to pass in and construct it that way...

Comment: You need one input for each value - other wise your just posting back a string and you would need to use `string.Split()` in the controller

Comment: @David Thanks for the comment but it didn't work.

Comment: @EricHotinger That does indeed work (four hidden fields with different values in), however, it doesn't quite fit my needs, since I need to update with JavaScript depending on what's selected above. I guess I'm back to parsing a comma split string. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should be posting a model which includes properties to select.

Comment: @bgs264 Why not make a [custom model binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) where you can convert comma-delimited string into an IEnumerable<int>?